# Переосмысление БД

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть товары (`Winner` - `ID_ticket`):

```
ID_product  Name_product    ID_seller   Winner
    1           iPhone          2          3
    2           iPhone          2          4
```

И билеты к ним.

```
ID_ticket   ID_product   ID_user
    3            1          1
    4            1          3
```

Суть вопроса:

- как изменить таблицы, чтобы у продавца была возможность ставить на продажу несколько экземпляров товара, при этом, не дублируя записи в БД? Когда заканчиваются билеты, то у продукта изменяется поле `Winner` на `ID_ticket` победителя.

Comment: По хорошему только связующей таблицей из двух полей ID_Product Winner. Только еще надо будет контролировать что бы в ней записей было не больше, чем выставлялось товаров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, у вас в первой таблице Winner это ссылка на ID_ticket из второй таблицы? Тогда зачем вы дублируете эту информацию указывая во второй таблице ID_product? Если убрать у билета эту ссылку, то у вас и появится возможность привязать один билет к нескольким товарам, без дублирования записей. Или я не правильно понял вашу задачу. В таком случае объясните подробнее ваш бизнес процесс.

Comment: Нет, один билет - один товар. Поле Winner содержит ссылку на ID_ticket, который выиграл данный товар.

Comment: тогда не ясно, в чем заключается проблема? Или вам нужно теперь реализовать вариант с несколькими победителями?

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать вариант, в котором у меня не будут дублироваться одинаковые товары от одного продавца. Т.е. если у продавца товар в 2 экземпляре, нужно чтобы запись этого товара не дублировался. Соотвественно победителя будет 2, по 1 на каждый экземпляр товара.

Comment: Если так, то поле winner убирать из таблицы товаров, и либо создавать связующую таблицу, как вам посоветовали, либо добавлять в таблицу билетов поле is_winner со значениями 1/0, изначально заполнять туда 0, а потом у выигравших билетов ставить 1;

Comment: Это понятно, но! Билетов может быть ограниченное количество для одного товара, допустим 10. А т.к. билеты связываются по ID_product, то и если у нас 2 экземпляра одного товара, то произойдет путаница, т.к. ID_product у билетов будет тот же.

Comment: В чем будет путаница? При определении победителей? Делаем выборку из таблицы билетов с одним id_product и у случайных десяти из них поднимаем флаг  is_winner (для десяти делаем записи в связующей таблице). Или при выдаче товара? Приходит человек с билетом за товаром, нам надо определить, является ли он победителем: смотрим, если у билета стоит is_winner и ID_product совпадает с нашим товаром - выдаем товар.

Comment: Путаница будет из-за того, что только 1 победитель, на 1 экземпляр. В таблице продуктов, будет 1 запись ID_product = 1 и count=2. Когда 10 билетов будут куплены, то товар автоматически отойдет одному из этих 10 билетов. Все билеты будут вида ID_product = 1. ID_ticket = *. Но когда начнется продажа билетов на 2-й экземпляр товара, то ID_product останется прежним, а билеты должны быть новые. Но т.к. ID_product остается тот же, то в таблице билетов должны появиться еще 10 записей, у которых будет ID_product = 1. Вот тут уже и появляется путаница.

Comment: Ага, т.е. проблема в том, чтобы отличить сыгравшие билеты, от тех по которым розыгрыша еще не было? Ок, тогда берем второй вариант, с дополнительным полем  is_winner в таблице билетов. Только поле у нас теперь имеет три значения -1,0 и 1 (проигрыш, неопределенность, выигрыш). Новые билеты инициализируем нулем. При розыгрыше выбираем билеты у которых is_winner = 0, ставим 1 победителям и -1 проигравшим.

Comment: В теории, это решает проблему. Надеюсь на практике будет так же. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Еще такая вам идея: Ввести таблицу розыгрышей. У каждого Розыгрыша будет свой уникальный id. Каждый билет хранит ссылку на розыгрыш, в котором он участвовал. А розыгрыш хранит ссылку на id билета победителя. В этом случае у еще не разыгранных билетов id розыгрыша будет пустым. А в таблице розыгрышей можно хранить еще всякую полезную информацию. Например такую как дата проведения розыгрыша. Это позволит в будущем проанализировать, какие билеты в каких розыгрышах участвовали.

Comment: Думаю, это будет лишним. Т.к. билеты создаются по запросу пользователя, а не сразу. А значит если билет создан, значит он уже 100% участвует в розыгрыше. Идея с is_winner должны решить мою проблему.